# Should an interface covariant on T ever implement an interface invariant on it?

Tags: interfaces, type-systems, generics, hiphop

I was reading through the Hacklang docs on Collections, and came across this curious definition [paraphrased slightly]:

```
interface KeyedIterable<Tk, Tv> ...
interface ConstVector<+Tv> implements KeyedIterable<int, Tv>  ...
```

Of course, [`KeyedIterable`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/interface/HH.KeyedIterable/) must be read-only with respect to Tv, and indeed it is since its methods cannot modify its type. It *could* be specified to be covariant on at least `Tv`, but isn't.

I was wondering what impetus there could be to do this?

---

**Edit:** I read the definition wrong, `KeyedIterable` is actually defined as `KeyedIterable<Tk, +Tv>`, so this definition makes perfect sense. I'm just realizing now that it's not so much "should or should not", but rather "this is never possible".

Comment: To do what?  Create an interface definition that, even though the designers could have specified to be covariant on tv, they didn't?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that's my confusion? I fail to see what the design incentive is to not make the parent class covariant on Tv, here or ever.

Answer (score 0):

No, an interface covariant on T should never implement an interface invariant on it. Covariance and invariance are different type variance concepts used in programming languages, particularly in relation to type hierarchies and polymorphism.

Covariance allows a more derived (or more specific) type to be used in place of a less derived (or less specific) type. In other words, it preserves the subtype relationship. For example, if we have an interface IFruit and a more specific interface IApple that extends IFruit, covariance would allow a function expecting an IFruit to accept an IApple as well.

Comment: Invariance include: The sort to be relegated and the sort appointed should be something very similar. This truly intends that there is no switch between a Youngster (More Inferred) type and a Parent (Less Determined) type. Covariance include: You can change from a Kid type to a Parent type.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose interface KeyedIterable implements a method Combine that takes another KeyedIterable instance and merges it with itself. That would result in a mixed collection of different types. Then there may be a method GetTotal that adds all the values in the collection and returns the result. That could blow up, the plus may be overloaded for the subtype and be incompatible with the add of the base type.

This explanation appears to be appreciated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w/674090#674090

Comment: No, this is a bad example. He explicitly stated that KeyedIterable is read-only. This is just a bunch of hypotheticals that would basically just amount to "Because the interface design is shit", instead of any compelling reason.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that part. Here's another thought. Isn't the KeyedIterable Tv implicitly covariant since it follows the ConstVector Tv? After all, there will be only one Tv at a time (per class declaration). You cannot have one value type for ConstVector and another for KeyedIterable. So a + or - with the second Tv would be meaningless.

Comment: Though in this particular case, another class `ConstMap<+Tk, +Tv>` implements KeyedIterable as well. My question actually comes from a specific use case: it's proven valuable to be able to return either Maps or Vectors, but annoyingly the invariance of Tk in KeyedIterable makes this impossible.

Comment: I was wrong here too: I had assumed that `ConstMap` was covariant on `Tk` like the rest of the `Const` family (outside of `ConstMapAccess` and `ConstIndexAccess` which are consequently why `ConstMap` is invariant on `Tk`). [I opened and subsequently closed a GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/6962) covering this.